# While building gettext 0.20 getting error: redefinition of ‘vasprintf’

Tags: c, mingw, gettext

I trying to compile gettext 0.20 using mingw tool chain on Windows 10, it is giving error as follow.

```
    In file included from lib-asprintf.c:46:
vasprintf.c:38:1: error: redefinition of ‘vasprintf’
   38 | vasprintf (char **resultp, const char *format, va_list args)
      | ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from vasnprintf.c:70,
                 from lib-asprintf.c:31:
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/stdio.h:262:5: note: previous definition of ‘vasprintf’ was here
  262 | int vasprintf(char **__ret, const char *__format, __builtin_va_list __local_argv)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from lib-asprintf.c:47:
asprintf.c:29:1: error: redefinition of ‘asprintf’
   29 | asprintf (char **resultp, const char *format, ...)
      | ^~~~~~~~
In file included from vasnprintf.c:70,
                 from lib-asprintf.c:31:
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/stdio.h:251:5: note: previous definition of ‘asprintf’ was here
```

I have used following configure command.

```
./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix="/cygdrive/c/gettext_build" \
        CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc \
        CXX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ \
        CPPFLAGS="-I/cygdrive/c/gettext_build/include -Wall" \
        LDFLAGS="-L/cygdrive/c/gettext_build/lib" --with-libiconv-prefix="/cygdrive/c/Apps/iconv-1.9.2.win32"
```

I have also tried to fix it as follows but it didn't help.

https://git.p-fb.net/pef/esp8266-open-compiler/blob/master/crosstool-NG/lib/crosstool-ng-1.22.0-60-g37b07f6f/patches/gettext/0.19.6/110-Fix-linker-error-redefinition-of-vasprintf.patch